# html control site with overlay popup

Tags: html, cookies, popup

Long shot but i'm hoping someone might be able to help or advise. We have a basic html website and we're trying to add a overlay pop up with a accept cookie.

General idea is have people accepting the cookie before they are able to browse the website. I believe the cookie should remember if the person has visited the site before.

Does anyone have an example of how this should look like? A code snippet of some sort?

I'd really appreciate some advice, even if it's literally just to get the basic idea to work.

Answer (score 0):

So heres the script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='popup'>
    <div class='cnt223'>
        <!--<div class="popupCloseButton">&times;</div>-->
        <h1 style="font-size: 18px;">Mholweni, Hello, Goeie dag!</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;">We respect your rights. Please read our Usage Agreement <a href="https://www.saonline.africa/use.html" target="_blank" style="color: #1b305c !important; font-weight: 300;"><u>HERE</u></a>.</p>
        <div class="popupAcceptButton"><font style="font-size: 15px;">I ACCEPT AND WANT TO PROCEED</font></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

What i'm really looking for is when i press "I ACCEPT AND WANT TO PROCEED" a cookie need to be created. At the moment this popup keep coming back if the site is refreshed.

I did try this however can't get the cookie generated when the button is clicked.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(getCookie("HideDiv") != "true")
  {
    $(".popupAcceptButton").css('display','yes');
  }

});

function SetCookieAndHideDiv(){
 setCookie('HideDiv','true',1);
 $(".popupAcceptButton").css('display','yes');
}

function getCookie(cname) {
     var name = cname + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
     }
     return "";
 } 

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
     var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly:

To create a pop-up you have to add javascript code; in particular you have to add an **alert** which says to an user if it is the first time that he logs in the site or not.

An example:

```
alert("It is the first time that you log in the site");
```

To register logins of users, you can use a database or a file where you will save the users ID or username already logged in.

Comment: Hmm perhaps an example like this https://cookiescan.com/?ref=rsaeul473&gclid=CjwKCAiA-_L9BRBQEiwA-bm5fgeZ9G2blp4qPALaWOXzF1ETNvdPuwaHSvz8kCSjjyAVZJiUEVpGaRoCGSAQAvD_BwE

Comment: Users visiting the site is forced to click accept before proceeding to the site.

Comment: Just something way more basic like an Accept button

Comment: CookieScan is a plugin. Obviusly you can use it. I thought you wanted to make this plugin' work by yourself.